# Zend Framework: How to create controller in WINXP on command line

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend framework with windows XP and WAMP server.

I have created zend project using following DOS commands:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0    
C:\>wamp\www> C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create project test
```

and my project is created at:

```
C:\wamp\www\test
```

Now I have two questions.
Q.1: In which folder I will run my create controller zend command using DOS?

```
C:\wamp\www\test>
or
C:\wamp\www\test\application\controller>
```

Q:2 I have tried both above folder locations to run create controller command. I have following error. how to solve this?

```
COMMAND
C:\>wamp\www\test> C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create controller test

ERROR:
    Fatal Error: Cannot Redeclare class Zend_Loader in C:\wamp\www\test\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 31
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) the procedure looks like this:

**Create Project**
*working directory: htdocs*

```
zf.bat create project zftest
cd zftest
```

**Create module**
*working directory: htdocs/zftest*

```
zf.bat create module testmodule
```

**Create controller**
*working directory: htdocs/zftest*

```
zf.bat create controller testcontroller index-action testmodule
```

*Notice the working directory of each command*

Xampp is an application stack for several different platforms, it's use is mainly to be able to setup a working development platform in a fast and effecient way.

The indexaction parameter is there to create a default index action in the created controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer helped me about working directories. But I am getting same error mentioned in my question. I want to ask two questions related to your answer: 1. what is xampp? I am using only ZendFramework and DOS command line in WINXP. 2. In your third command(Create Controller) what is the purpose of 'index-action testmodule'. I am new to zend framework and your answer will help me.

Thanks

Comment: See my edited answer. About the testmodul it's there to specify in which module to create the controller.

Comment: I got my answer for Fatal Error. See accepted answer. Your answer helped me about directory structure. Thanks