# Zend problems creating controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to zend, so I'm working through this tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOwSfKXKpZQ&feature=relmfu). If you skip to about 1:10, he creates a new contoller, and then types the name of it in the url.
This brings up the appropriate view. All good. However, when I do it I get a big NOT FOUND and this '*The requested URL /cube was not found on this server*'.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

Sorry if this is a little vague, if you need more details, let me know.

Here's a few you may need:

**Server:** Xampp

**OS:** Windows Vista 32bit

**Zend version:** 1.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have correctly configured `.htaccess` file in the project's root directory? Take a look at [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter). You have to have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache. This can be done by editing the `httpd.conf` file, which should be in the Apache installation folder. Then you should add a `.htaccess` file into the root folder of you project with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Or alternatively one can use ZF without mod_rewrite. To do so, configure front controller this way:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setBaseUrl('/url/to/app/index.php')
```

Comment: It's possible. I can't say I particularly understand htaccess configuration, so this link's great for me thanks. I'll get back once I've had a read and a ponder.

Comment: Took me some time, I had all sorts of unrelated problems with my server. Anyway, the main thing was that I didn't configure my `http.conf` file correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on DOS command line:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0    
C:\>wamp\www> C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create controller test
```

*use correct path for zf.bat and php*

If still some problem then comment out this line in **application.ini** and try again

```
;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

I faced this problem earlier. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734166/zend-framework-how-to-create-controller-in-winxp-on-command-line). Hope this will help.